# Spring MVC + Security. @Secured + @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class APIProvider {
    @Secured(value = {"isAuthenticated()"})
    @RequestMapping(value="/secure/{app}/{query}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> getList(HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathVariable("app") String app,
        @PathVariable("query") String query) {
        //....DO SMTH
    }
}
```

When trying to access the needed URL I get 'Page not found.'

Removing the `@Secured` annotation, fixes the problem. So the Request mapping is right.
Also for `@Secured` annotation I have added the following instruction to security-config.xml:

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Can anyone help me to make `@Secured` + `@RequestMapping` working together?

Comment: My guess would be the isAuthenticated() cannot be resloved. I think you should go with @Secured(value="ROLE_AUTHENTICATED")

Comment: Still got the 'Page Not Found'. Should I define the role ROLE_AUTHENTICATED in the security-config.xml? Or it is predefined by spring itself?

Comment: It depends on how you configured your authenticationProvider i think, since we use an sso our default role is ROLE_AUTHENTICATED :  <beans:bean id="ssoAuthenticationProvider"  class="foo.bar.authentication.SSOAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:property name="credentialsBinder" ref="credentialsBinder" />
  <beans:property name="credentialsHTTPClient" ref="credentialsHTTPClient" />
  <beans:property name="rolesPrefix" value="ROLE_" />
  <beans:property name="minutesValid" value="60" />
  <beans:property name="defaultRole" value="ROLE_AUTHENTICATED" />
 </beans:bean>

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead `@Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")`.

Comment: Still got the 'Page Not Found' message

Answer (score 0):

In your security.xml file, after *<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>* add following line:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/secure/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated() />
</http>
```

This will make sure, all your /api/secure requests will be served if user is fully authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include security expression handler as well.

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" >
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>

<beans:bean id="expressionHandler"   class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHa ndler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>
```